# Why is PyCharm not recognizing .mp3 files?

Tags: file, audio, pycharm, mp3

PyCharm isn't recognizing the .mp3 files, is there any solution to this?

I tried adding a new file type, messed around with the file associations and such but broke no ground. There are no audio file types in the given list in PyCharm, so how do I get the audio files to be recognized in PyCharm?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.